# node.js socke.io chat app : not sending message between two browser windows where is my mistake

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

js code. which is a server file
while i am running this below code it is not sending messages when i click the button.

```
var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(8000,function(){
console.log("The server is listening on the port 8000");
});
app.use(express.static('public'));
var io = socket(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket){
socket.on("chat", function(data){
    io.sockets.emit("chat", data);
  });
});
```

here is my index.html code which also contains
and css file which i am not included here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>my first chat app</title>
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mario-chat">
        <div id="chat-window">
            <div id="output"></div>
            <div id="feedback"></div>
        </div>
        <input id="handle" type="text" placeholder="Handle"/>
        <input id="message" type="message" placeholder="Message"/>
        <button id="send">Send</button>
    </div>
    <script src="/chat.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

the above code include a stylesheet.css file for looking good.
here is my chat.js file which is client side functionalities.

```
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8000");
var message = document.getElementById("message");
var handle = document.getElementById("handle");
var btn = document.getElementById("send");
var output = document.getElementById("output");
var feedback = document.getElementById("feedback");
btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
socket.emit("chat", {message:message.value,handle:handle.value});
 });
socket.on("chat", function(data){
output.innerHTML += '<p><strong>' + data.handle + ':</strong>' +
data.message + '</p>';
 });
```

please rectify me where i am doing mistakes
thanks in advance.

Comment: In your server code, you should have `socket.on` rather than `socket.emit` (the first one)

Comment: and it should listen to `click` and not `chat`

Comment: i had edited my code as above but still it is not working pleae help me where i am doing mistake

Comment: i included chat.js , index.html and style.css in public folder under main chat folder. can any one pls help me where is the mistake

Comment: `output.innerHTML+ = ...` should be `output.innerHTML += ...`

Comment: hi robertklep i changed the code as per your suggestion but still not working

Comment: really cant understand why it is not working ... seeems everthing i wrote is correct even i tested with console.log upto where it is executing then i got that it is executing the Socket connection code , but it is not emiting the events. please any one can help me

Comment: can anyone please check the code and correct me.   Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your client code socket must be created with `ws` protocol. So, 
`io.connect("http://localhost:8000");` should be `io.connect("ws://localhost:8000");`

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Socket.IO will always initially connect using HTTP, and _might_ upgrade to a WebSocket connection.